# Describe in detail the boot process of a Linux system

Tags: linux, boot, boot-loader, netboot

I am preparing a document in detail showing light on the boot sequence of Linux right from pressing of Power-on button the host to the login prompt appearance.

It would be great if we could combine and collate that right answers here into a single place of reference. Please include any details worth possible to note during the startup.
Once the document gets complete from all the points, I will post the document details here as well and update the link in the question.

Please consider all possible scenarios like booting from disk, booting from usb, booting from network on a disk-less client where the rootfs(/) is on network.

Comment: Judging from [this (including references)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process) and [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linuxboot/), you propose quite a huge project...

Comment: Does this feel like a homework/thesis question to anyone else?

Comment: if this is a question of thesis and does not fit in UL, please move it to the right QA site.  Home work? I do not think so. I have already said that I am preparing to write a detailed document on it, could do so with whatever I could put my hands on but its likely that I might have missed some and with the expert base at UL, it is likely I will get closer in understanding.

Comment: Shouldn't it then be flagged as community-wiki?

Comment: good idea, makes sense to upload there once I have something concrete and shape. btw, I am not sure whether community wiki exists for UL. Does it?

Comment: I think this is far too broad for a question on SE, there are huge variations between distributions and configurations.

Comment: This is by far the best X86/Linux booting presentation I've found. It's over 2hrs and it's dense, lots of assembly and hardware architecture bits, so it's not just Linux commandline stuff. http://excess.org/article/2008/08/oclug-august-kernel-walkthrough-boot-process/

Comment: can you please post the document prepared by you

Answer (score 7):

You want booting sequence of Linux or just PC booting sequence ... because there is no difference between booting Linux from usb/cdrom/hdd ... Linux is always booting from MBR where the bootloader is ...

Linux boot process:

1. As power comes up the BIOS is given control
2. BIOS runs self tests, usually including cursory memory tests.
3. The BIOS then loads the first sector of the disk to be used for booting and transfers control to it.
4. The MBR code varies. One version will chain to the code in the first sector of the boot partition (Windows), another will load a bootloader. Windows boot proceeds from code and information in the boot partition.
5. bootloader chooses kernel location and version
6. bootloader prepares kernel and initrd image in memory, transfers control to kernel
7. loading kernel modules
8. discovering hardware and load additional kernel modules to support it
9. looking for disks
10. R/O mount of / partition so that it can potentially be checked and repaired
11. init process spawn
12. /etc/inittab read and executing
13. mounting all FSes from /etc/fstab
14. runlevels running (based on default runlevel in /etc/inittab) or another init method such as systemd or upstart
15. rc.local
16. login prompt

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian, that was a good list. I am looking for detailed steps for example 1: what loads mbr info, before that how is post and bios instructions are flowing; 2. why r/o mount of / partition and then again read/write mount / partition .. what is process 0 in this whole process.. but thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Nikhil regarding process 0 ... there is no such process, after kernel load You have process 1, which is init process.
Regarding rest of points:  
1. check http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linuxboot/index.html  
2. because first it needs to be checked files, then You can start write on it ... it's rather for security reasons ...

Comment: There is no MBR on floppies or cdroms.  The boot process for cdroms involves a catalog file that describes one or more multi sector images that the bios can choose to load and execute.

Comment: What if the kernel modules are on a `ext3` file system and the `ext3` kernel module is not loaded yet? What's more, what if the kernel itself is on a file system that bootloader doesn't recognize? How is the following things loaded in sequence, loading `kernel`, loading `bootloader`, mounting `/boot` directory, reading `/etc/fstab` file, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing and using [bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/).

Comment: thanks for the pointer, am actually looking to present a visualizing flow document of what happens during boot and what kind  of decision making is involved in.

Comment: thanks @Alexander I installed it on my fedora and it provides very detailed png